Como podria editar mi navbar de wordpress nativo con bootstrap
¿qué tal estoy haciendo un navbar en WordPress nativo, he intentado modificarlo con bootstrap, pero no me funciona y necesito que quede responsivo Agradeceria mucho la ayuda recién comienzo en el desarrollo y me cuesta un poco

¿Cual es tu tema?, ¿Lo hiciste tu mismo?, ¿Dónde esta el código?, ¿Esta en tu header.php?, ¿Tienes styles personalizados?, ¿Creaste un plugin? o ¿Lo hiciste por snippet?, ¿Usaste un page builder como elementor? Aquí ayudamos con problemas de código,  lastimosamente no somos adivinos, por favor lee [ask] y como hacer un [example]

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.
